Should we merge the Sorting and Organizing tags?
At the moment we've got 3 questions that are tagged sorting, 2 of which are also tagged organization, the remaining one could be equally happy under organization I think?

The tags more or less represent the same questions. The question is which one of the two tags should be the preferred tag. 
I've added sorting as a suggested synonym for organisation which can be voted on here.

Seeing as my vote's not an insta-approve, I've voted on that. Wasn't sure if suggesting it as a mod would have just created it. Clearly not.

I would have kinda expected it that way too, but you can actually force it anywy on the general synonyms page where there's an "approve" link (well, was, since I just did it). That said, I kinda liked [tag:sorting]... oh well

@Joubarc Yes, I knew about the insta-approve, but was deliberately not using it as I wasn't sure about how the rest of us felt...

Ah, "oops", then.
